# Как сохранить и восстановить базу данных PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Например, имеется пользователь *postgres*, база *base* и доступ *trust*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Для сохранения кластера базы данных:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -w > backup
```

Для восстановления кластера базы данных:

```
psql -U postgres -w -f backup postgres
```

Answer (score 6):

Бекап базы:

```
pg_dump -v -h 127.0.0.0 -F c -U postgres -W -f "base.backup" base
```