# Как получить значения всех элементов с одним классом?

Tags: javascript

Имеется страница, на которой есть множество элементов с одинаковыми классами, с которых нужно вытащить значения классов "data-id=", "data-float=", "data-original-title" для каждого элемента отдельно. Опыта вообще не имею, но очень хочу понять как оно работает. Буду премного благодарен за помощь. Скрин структуры страницы ниже. По сути это нужно, чтобы полученные данные сравнить с переменной и при совпадении одного из элементов с ней - покрасить фон, к примеру[image: структура страницы]

Comment: [документация](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom)

Comment: Если бы мне помогала такая документация, я бы не спрашивал тут ответа. Я по ней уже пытался работать, но руки кривые, или я не то делаю, не знаю. Как достать значения из элементов, которые находятся под такой структурой? Значения Name Float Price? https://jsfiddle.net/590zdvb2/1/

Comment: `element.getAttribute('my-attribute');`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const output = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll('.list__item')].forEach(item => {
  output.push({
    price: item.getAttribute('data-price'),
    float: item.getAttribute('data-float')
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <div class="list__item" data-price="100" data-float="1">1</div>
  <div class="list__item" data-price="200" data-float="2">2</div>
  <div class="list__item" data-price="300" data-float="3">3</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Зачем вы преобразовали `NodeList` в массив?

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов, к чему вопрос? какой ответ Вы ожидаете на него получить?

Comment: ну просто у `NodeList` же есть свой `forEach`. Просто, может быть, у них какие-то различия, из-за чего вы решили его преобразовать.

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов, в данном случае, в принципе, не имеет значение(нет фильтра и т.д.), если углубляться, то там уже нужно развивать тему про "живой" и "статичный" список (NodeList, HTMLCollection), где-то я уже видел на форуме подобный вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".just4fest")].map(e => ({
  dataId: e.getAttribute('data-id'),
  dataSrc: e.getAttribute('data-src')
})));
```

```html
<div class="just4fest" data-id="1" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="2" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="3" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="4" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="5" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="6" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6"></div>
```

Как верно подметил `@Alexander Lonberg`, запись можно сократить, используя деструктуризацию. В таком случае вы получите все атрибуты с префиксом `data-`.

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".just4fest")].map(({dataset}) => dataset));
```

```html
<div class="just4fest" data-id="1" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="2" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="3" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="4" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="5" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5"></div>
<div class="just4fest" data-id="6" data-src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6"></div>
```

Comment: `.map(({dataset}) => dataset))`

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, да, спасибо большое, дополню ответ :)

Comment: Вспомнил еще - если много `data-` и необходимо вытащить только некоторые, можно так `.map(({dataset:d={id, src}}) => d))`

Comment: Ого, признаюсь честно, первый раз такое вижу. Довольно интересно, спасибо)

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, в данном случае, насколько я понимаю, запись вида `.map(({dataset:d={id, src}}) => d))` не сработает, поскольку `dataset` имеется в деструктурируемом обьекте. А данная запись говорит `возьми {id, src}, если dataset === undefined`

Comment: Но можно преобразовать в запись вида `.map(({dataset, d={id:dataset.id}}) => d))`, она работает)

Comment: `dataset` есть всегда и это объект. Далее мы это можем переименовать переменную, это делается так `dataset: newName`, но так как это объект мы его деструктурируем в несколько свойств-переменных `{dataset:{id, src}`. А теперь чтоб не перетаскивать их в тело функции, присваиваем новой переменной `d={id, src}`

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, все таки я склоняюсь к тому, что запись  `dataset: newName` это переименование, `dataset=100` - деструктуризация со значением по умолчанию. А `dataset: newName=100` переименование со значением по умолчанию. Прошу прощения, чат создал случайно, у меня к нему даже доступа нет.

Comment: Денис, я не прав. Запарился от бессоницы и даже не проверил. Это действительно параметр по умолчанию. Тогда только так `.map(({dataset:{id, src}}) => ({id, src})))`. Я применял это совсем по другому `({prop:{...}}, d={...})`, когда надо было определить переменные вне тела функции. Но с Array.map такого не прокатит. Каюсь :(